# Packaging a Python script and the modules it needs

Tags: python

I developed a Python script that uses some libs (Pandas, Numpy, bs4, etc.).

The problem is that the customer environment is shared, so I cannot install these libraries with 'pip'. He asked me to "put these libraries in the script"...

Is there any way to pack a python script with the related libraries? Can Software like PyInstaller be helpful?

Comment: DO you want it to remain a Python script, be packed as an exe, or are both good?

Comment: why do you need to use the same environment?

Comment: Yes, PyInstaller can do this.

Comment: @AvivAviv yes. I need a Python script working on Linux.

Comment: @Sayse, unfortunately, this is a customer's requisite.